# SQL Select the Columnid with a max column group by one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I think this question is already answered but it didn't satisfy my question.

I'd like to select the id/s of the names group by the latest date value (`MAX`) in my table. Using a group by column `Name` and group by column `Date`, I must get the `ID`, `Name`, `Date`.

Here is my table

```
ID            Name           Date
---------------------------------------
1             Brent          2012-02-17
2             Ash            2012-08-02
3             Brent          2012-08-15
4             Harold         2012-09-30
5             Margaret       2012-10-10
6             Ash            2012-12-01
7             Harold         2013-02-14
8             Ash            2012-01-01
9             Brent          2013-05-11
```

Output must be:

```
ID            Name           Date
---------------------------------------
5             Margaret       2012-10-10
6             Ash            2012-12-01
7             Harold         2013-02-14
9             Brent          2013-05-11
```

I try this statement:

```
 SELECT 
    [ID], [Name], MAX([Date]) as [Date]
 FROM 
    [SampleTable]
 GROUP BY 
    [Name]
```

But I get this error:

> Column 'ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use *Window Function* such as `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name, a.Date
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Name, Date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM    TableName
) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

if `ID` and `Name` is the same for every group, you can simply add `Name` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

Comment: What if my ID's aren't not in sequence(1, 2, 3, 4,..., n). Does it still make sense the problem?

Comment: @Brent it doesn't matter. `ROW_NUMBER()` generates sequential number. Please see [Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189798.aspx)